# Instantiating a base class inside of a scope and calling outside the scope is not working

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I am having a segmentation fault problem with the following main function. "base" is an instance of the base class, "baseOne" is an instance of a derived class. When I call `base->foo()` inside the scope, the function works properly, but when I call it outside the scope, I get a segmentation fault. How can I make `base->foo()` work outside of the scope?

`main.cpp`

```
#include "Handler.hpp"
#include "Derived.hpp"

using namespace std;
int main(){
    Base* base;
    {
        Derived_factory factoryOne("Derived.so");
        std::unique_ptr<Base> baseOne = factoryOne.create();
        Base* b;
        b = baseOne.release();
        base=b;
        base->foo();
    }
    base->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, the following code works, even though it is not appropriate for my program.

```
#include "Handler.hpp"
#include "Derived.hpp"

using namespace std;
int main(){
    Base* base;
    {
        Base* b = new Derived();
        base=b;
        base->foo();
    }
    base->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The rest of the code is below.

`base.hpp`

```
    class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() {}
        virtual void foo() = 0;
    };

    using Base_creator_t = Base *(*)();
```

`derived.hpp`

```
#include "Base.hpp"

class A{
public:
    int k;
    void printsomething(){
        std::cout<<"class A "<<k<<std::endl;
    };
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    A a;
    void virtual foo(){
       std::cout<<"Hello Foo! Derived Class"<<std::endl;
       returnA();
    };
    void printA(){
      a.k = 10;
      a.printsomething();
    };
};
extern "C" {
  Base * create() {
    return new Derived;
  }
}
```

`handler.hpp`

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "Base.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Derived_factory {
public:
    Derived_factory(char* path) {
        handler = dlopen(path, RTLD_NOW);
        if (! handler) {
            throw std::runtime_error(dlerror());
        }
        Reset_dlerror();
        creator = reinterpret_cast<Base_creator_t>(dlsym(handler, "create"));
        Check_dlerror();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Base> create() const {
        return std::unique_ptr<Base>(creator());
    }

    ~Derived_factory() {
        if (handler) {
            dlclose(handler);
        }
    }

private:
    void * handler = nullptr;
    Base_creator_t creator = nullptr;

    static void Reset_dlerror() {
        dlerror();
    }

    static void Check_dlerror() {
        const char * dlsym_error = dlerror();
        if (dlsym_error) {
            throw std::runtime_error(dlsym_error);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: what is `Base_creator_t` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is a type defined in base.hpp and used in handler.cpp

Comment: oh right, my bad

Comment: Your `main.cpp` fails to compile, most likely because of missing `#include`s.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond you have to include hpp files. I removed include files to have a reduced size code.

Comment: in the Derived_factory destructor, that gets called at the end of factoryOne scope, you close the handler. Do you still get the same error if you comment the dlclose(handler)?
It looks like the Derived class code is in a shared library, and you are trying to call it after the library has been unloaded.